# Input.deviceOrientation Vs Screen.orientation

Tags: unity-game-engine

As my title suggest, what is the difference between **Input.deviceOrientation** to **Screen.orientation**.

When to use each of this?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I haven't tested my theories, but reading the manual [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-orientation.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-deviceOrientation.html), my understanding is the following:

- **Input.deviceOrintation** is a read-only property, that gives back the physical orientation of the device, REPORTED BY THE OS. I would use this property to determine that what orientation is used by the user. (It probably depends on the OS's auto-rotation settings too.)
- **Screen.orientation** is not a read only property. It is the setting you can also set in Unity3D's "Player Settings". This property can be changed, and changing it will most likely change the layout and coordinates of your Unity3D scene (effectively turning it by 90 degrees increments).

Please correct me in the comments if I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Gabor for your quick reply, let me test this in actual game and reply back to you :)

Comment: Still I think more appropriate answer possible so I am just doing upvote to this reply, waiting for more clear reply.

Comment: I'm trying to come up a with a scenario here... Let's say I want the game to be usable in both landscape and portrait mode, and make it auto-rotate in-game. But while play-testing, I realize that sudden scene-orientation change can cause the player's car drop off a cliff or something... So I decide that the screen may be rotated only while in the pause menu. Then when the game is paused, I check the value of **Input.deviceOrintation**, and set the value of **Screen.orientation** accordingly. Of course Screen.orientation should never be set AutoRotation in this theoretical case. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

`Input.deviceOrientation` provides the orientation that the device is held at. This can report orientations that don't correspond to screen orientations (e.g. `FaceUp`, `FaceDown`).

`Screen.orientation` tells you the orientation of the image on the screen so can only be one of four values. You can also set this to change the orientation. Setting it to `AutoRotation` will immediately cause the property to return the actual orientation - i.e. this property will never return `ScreenOrientation.AutoRotation`.

`Screen.orientation` will often match `Input.deviceOrientation` (not literally, as they use different enums) - but most obviously these won't match when the device is flat. In this case the screen orientation will be whatever device orientation was before the device was placed flat.

I would use `Screen.orientation` if you want to know which way round the user perceives the app to be on their device. This is also useful when using a  `WebCamTexture` input as these textures need to be rotated when the screen is rotated (though the texture itself has a property to help with this). `Input.deviceOrientation` seems less useful - perhaps there are games you could use this for, but the accelerometer would probably be more useful for this.